# Piping ListView items in separate runspace

Tags: winforms, listview, powershell, runspace, powershell-5.0

I have a form written in PowerShell (as it uses PS to run commands over hundreds of servers) but this bit had me stumped for awhile:

```
$listview.Invoke([System.Action[String]]{
    Param
    (
        [String]$data
    )
    write-warning "1"
    $LVitem = ($LVresults.Items | Where { $_.Name -eq "Test Account" })
    write-warning "2"
    $LVitem.Tag.Output += $data + "`n"
}, "Testing")
```

It's in a separate runspace that runs an Invoke-Command to a specific server and pipes the output to this code block.

Now if I run the Where statement in the main runspace (where the form is created) it works perfectly fine. In the separate runspace however it locks up the form. Warning 1 is displayed, Warning 2 is not.

Piping to a Foreach statement has the same problem, but I can use:

```
Foreach ($item in $listview.Items) { 
    if ($item.Name -eq "Test Account") { $LVitem = $item }
}
```

Can anyone explain this? I'm not doing anything fancy with the ListView or its items, it just seems the ListView doesn't like its items being piped in another runspace.

Comment: Will it locks up the form if you replace `$LVitem = ($LVresults.Items | Where { $_.Name -eq "Test Account" })` with `{}.Invoke()`?

Comment: Huh. It does, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem with PowerShell event system. It deadlocks when event handler generate event with wait to completion option.

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyEvent1 -Action {Write-Host 'Does not get called.'}
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyEvent2 -Action {$ExecutionContext.Events.GenerateEvent('MyEvent1',$null,$null,$null,$true,$true)}
New-Event -SourceIdentifier MyEvent2
```

So, what your setup have to do with events?

Script blocks literals remembers current session state (including `Runspace`) at creation time. And if at script block invocation time current `Runspace` for current thread (`[Runspace]::DefaultRunspace`) is different or busy processing something in different thread, then script block invoked by generating event to original `Runspace` with wait to completion option.

Another interesting thing is that: if target `Runspace` does not start processing events in 250 milliseconds, then PowerShell start event processing in the thread waiting for event completion.

In your code you have two nested script block invokations:

1. Script block passed as delegate to `$listview.Invoke` method.
2. Script block passed to `Where-Object` cmdlet.

As I see, your code have three possible outcomes:

1. Script block's original `Runspace` is free, so script block executed in different thread (not UI thread).

   ```
   $PowerShell=[PowerShell]::Create()
   $PowerShell.Runspace=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
   $PowerShell.Runspace.Open()
   $Stopwatch=[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
   $PowerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set('Stopwatch',$Stopwatch)
   $ScriptBlock=$PowerShell.AddScript{{
       Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
       {Write-Host OK}.Invoke()
   }}.Invoke()
   $PowerShell.Commands.Clear()
   & {
       $Stopwatch.Start()
       Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
       $ScriptBlock.Invoke()
   }
   ```
2. Script block's original `Runspace` is busy, so script block executed in current thread and deadlocks on nested script block invocation.

   ```
   $PowerShell=[PowerShell]::Create()
   $PowerShell.Runspace=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
   $PowerShell.Runspace.Open()
   $Stopwatch=[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
   $PowerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set('Stopwatch',$Stopwatch)
   $ScriptBlock=$PowerShell.AddScript{{
       Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
       {Write-Host Deadlock}.Invoke()
   }}.Invoke()
   $PowerShell.Commands.Clear()
   & {
       $AsyncResult=$PowerShell.AddScript{Start-Sleep 10}.BeginInvoke()
       $Stopwatch.Start()
       Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
       $ScriptBlock.Invoke()
   }
   ```
3. Script block's original `Runspace` initially busy, but get free before nested script block invocation, so script block executed in current thread and does not deadlocks.

   ```
   $PowerShell=[PowerShell]::Create()
   $PowerShell.Runspace=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
   $PowerShell.Runspace.Open()
   $Stopwatch=[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
   $PowerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set('Stopwatch',$Stopwatch)
   $ScriptBlock=$PowerShell.AddScript{{
       Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
       Start-Sleep 10
       {Write-Host OK}.Invoke()
   }}.Invoke()
   $PowerShell.Commands.Clear()
   & {
       $AsyncResult=$PowerShell.AddScript{Start-Sleep 5}.BeginInvoke()
       $Stopwatch.Start()
       Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
       $ScriptBlock.Invoke()
   }
   ```

To workaround this issue you need to detach script block from its original `Runspace`. You can achieve that by creating new script block from string using `[ScriptBlock]::Create` method.

```
$PowerShell=[PowerShell]::Create()
$PowerShell.Runspace=[RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
$PowerShell.Runspace.Open()
$Stopwatch=[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$PowerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set('Stopwatch',$Stopwatch)
$ScriptBlock=$PowerShell.AddScript{[ScriptBlock]::Create{
    Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
    {Write-Host OK}.Invoke()
}}.Invoke()
$PowerShell.Commands.Clear()
& {
    $AsyncResult=$PowerShell.AddScript{Start-Sleep 10}.BeginInvoke()
    $Stopwatch.Start()
    Write-Host "$($Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds): $([Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)"
    $ScriptBlock.Invoke()
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough upvotes to give this answer. Thanks!