# WPF runspace crashes using powershell version 2

Tags: wpf, powershell, runspace

I'm writing a powershell script, which installes various drivers.

My script is working fine, so I want to add a gui using WPF.
First I created a gui using WPF, nothing spectacular, just a window with a label.

I would like to update this label from my install script. So I create two runspaces, one that creates and shows the WPF gui and the other one executes my install script.
That works fine as long as I'm using powershell version 3 or higher.  With powershell 2, which I had to use with a new Windows 7 installation, the wpf runspace crashes down.

I hope there is a way to get this working with powershell version 2.

Here is a sample script, demonstating what I'm doing.

```
#########################################################################################
#
#   W P F - R U N S P A C E
#
#########################################################################################
$syncHashWpfLuaNotification = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$runspaceWpfLuaNotification =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$runspaceWpfLuaNotification.ApartmentState = "STA"
$runspaceWpfLuaNotification.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$runspaceWpfLuaNotification.Open()
$runspaceWpfLuaNotification.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHashWpfLuaNotification",$syncHashWpfLuaNotification)          
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
    [xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TreiberInstaller" Height="431" Width="626" Background="Black"
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Name="lblProgress" Content="Progress"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
    $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.lblProgress = $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.window.FindName("lblProgress")
    $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Error = $Error
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $runspaceWpfLuaNotification
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
Sleep -Milliseconds 450 # Wait a moment that the gui is ready




#########################################################################################
#
#   W O R K E R - R U N S P A C E
#
#########################################################################################
$ScriptBlock = { 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #   SetLabelText: Sets the lable-text
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function SetLabelText
    {
        param(
                [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $false)]
                [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
                [string]$Text
            )

        if(-not $syncHashWpfLuaNotification) {return}

        try
        {
            $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
                    [action]{$syncHashWpfLuaNotification.lblProgress.Content = $Text},
                    "Normal"
            )
        }
        catch {}
    }

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #   CloseProgressWindow: Closes the window
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function CloseProgressWindow()
    {
        if(-not $syncHashWpfLuaNotification) {return}

        try
        {
            $syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
                    [action]{$syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window.Close()},
                    "Normal"
            )
        }
        catch{}
    }



    #Starting here
    SetLabelText -Text "Starting installation..."

    Sleep 2

    for($i=1;$i -le 19; $i++)
    {
        SetLabelText -Text ("Progress Step " + $i)
    }

    for($i=20;$i -le 24; $i++)
    {
        SetLabelText -Text ("Progress Step " + $i)
        Sleep 1
    }

    CloseProgressWindow
} #End of $ScriptBlock


$syncHash1 = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$workerRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$workerRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$workerRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$workerRunspace.Open()
$workerRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash1",$syncHash1)          
$workerRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHashWpfLuaNotification",$syncHashWpfLuaNotification)          
$psCmd1 = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
$psCmd1.Runspace = $workerRunspace
$data = $psCmd1.BeginInvoke()






#########################################################################################
#
#   S C R I P T   E N D   
#
#########################################################################################

#Wait for end of both runspaces
while(($runspaceWpfLuaNotification.RunspaceAvailability -eq "Busy") -or ($workerRunspace.RunspaceAvailability -eq "Busy"))
{
    if($runspaceWpfLuaNotification.RunspaceAvailability -eq "Busy") { Write-Host "Window is open" }
    if($workerRunspace.RunspaceAvailability -eq "Busy") { Write-Host "Worker is running" }

    Sleep 1
}

Write-Host "Script ended"
```

Comment: `[action]{$syncHashWpfLuaNotification.lblProgress.Content = $Text}, "Normal"` -> `"Normal", [action[object]][scriptblock]::create({$syncHashWpfLuaNotification.lblProgress.Content = $args[0]}), $Text`; `[action]{$syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window.Close()}, "Normal"` -> `"Normal", [action][scriptblock]::create({$syncHashWpfLuaNotification.Window.Close()})`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! This works fine with powershell 2.0. Thank's alot. You can post this as answer, so I'm able to marks this as right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with how your pass delegates to `Dispatcher.Invoke` call.

- `ScriptBlock` literals are bounded to current session state. If you pass bounded `ScriptBlock` to different `Runspace`, then it can cause some undesired effects, like code not invoked in target `Runspace` or deadlocks. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691632) about this. So, first thing you need to do is to create new not bounded `ScriptBlock`. You can do that with `[ScriptBlock]::Create` method.
- Since `ScriptBlock` is no more bounded to current session state, you can not refer variables from it, like you do with `$Text` in your code. You should pass them as additional parameters to `Dispatcher.Invoke`.
- In .NET Framework 3.5, which will be used with PowerShell v2, there is no `Invoke(Action, DispatcherPriority)` overload in `Dispatcher` class, so that, `Invoke([Action]{...}, "Normal")` will be resolved to this `Invoke(Delegate, Object[])` method instead. You should use different overload: `Invoke(DispatcherPriority, Delegate)`, which exists in .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading [WPFRunspace](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPFRunspace-a-BackgroundWor-7f30edc4), which should work with PS V2. It provides a background worker for WPF and Forms based scripts.